# Trying to run my app on an iphone simulator through VS Studio and Xcode and when I run the simulator I get this error:

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:416:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:241:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:240:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:161:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
[!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `9.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 13 Pro Max.
Exited

Answer (score 0):

Open Podfile. You will see a platform and commented  9.0. Uncomment it and change the version to 11..

```dart
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'
```

Run pod install in ios directory then open xc workspace file in xcode and build once. After this all subsequent builds will work from your ide

Answer (score 0):

### Try this method:

- i will face this error whenever i run a new project

```
cd iOS/
pod install
```

- then close emulator and vscode
- and run the project again!!